# How do I make browsing a Windows network work on Xubuntu?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, samba, cifs, thunar

I just installed Xubuntu 19.10. I like Linux and most things work great, but I can never get Windows networking to work.

When I open the File Manager it has a Browse Network page listed under NETWORK. On that page is a single icon: Windows Network. When I double click that I get an error saying "Failed to open "Windows Network".: Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory." - an unhelpful message giving no indication what's wrong or how to proceed.

How can I get this to work? I have Googled the problem, but everything I find is about:

- *Hosting* files on Linux via Windows networking - I'm not interested in that
- Various other ways of connecting to Windows shares (Gigolo, `smbclient`, etc.) - I'm not interested in that either (and in fact I can connect to shares using Gigolo); I'd like to get this UI to work

There are no other Windows machines on the network, but there is a Synology NAS which it should see at the very least, as well as a printer. When running Windows on this same machine network browsing works fine and it sees those. The fact that I can connect to shares using Gigolo must mean that the basic dependencies and configuration are present.

Comment: Have you installed `smbclient`? That is necessary to access Windows networks.

Comment: @Jos No. How do you know that? Where is that documented?

Comment: @Jos I have now installed it but unfortunately it makes no difference. I still get the same error.

Comment: What if you go to "Other locations" in the File Manager, then on the bottom connect to your NAS? You need to specify `smb://ip-address-of-nas`.

Comment: @Jos As I stated in the question: this question is about getting this UI to work. I know I can connect to Windows shares in other ways.

Comment: What version of WIndows are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I do not have your NAS but I have assisted those that do and this is from my notes:

> but there is a Synology NAS which it should see at the very least

It should see it automatically and not under Windows Network but under Browse Network directly but you have to tell Synology to do that. In the Control Panel > File Sharing > File Services > Advanced > Bonjour > Select **Enable Bonjour service discovery**

Bonjour allows Mac users to discover the NAS in their file manager automatically. Bonjour in Linux is called Avahi and it does the exact same thing. The only thing you need to do on the Linux side is make sure avahi is running:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon status
```

If for some reason it's not running start it:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon start
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I canot comment but can post an answer: @Morbius:
Note that I first had to do:

- sudo apt install avahi-discover

I can browse my windows shares on Ubunutu via nautilus but als had to do the following on my Windows machines:

- Start/Go to 'Turn Windows Features on or off', then select SMB1.0 and SMB direct. Apply and restart PC
- Download Bonjour WIndows SDK Kit (I used version 3.0 from softpedia).
  Install it. Then go to the directory where its control panel is installed (C:\Program Files\Bonjour SDK\bin). Then start the control panel by double clicking ControlPanel.exe. Next on the first tab enable 'Advertise Shared folders using Bonjour'. Thats probably all that is needed here but I also filled in my pc name, user name and password, and selected apply on the registration tab. I also added 'WORKGROUP', my pc name again and 'local' on the Browsing tab.
- I also went to Advanced Network Sharing  turned on Network Discovery for private netoworks. Check that you are in fact connected to a network that is 'private'. I also turned off 'Password protected sharing' under the heading 'All networks' Since this is a pc in a home network and not a laptop this is fine for me security wise.
- Finally just to be sure I restarted my PC.
- Then I went back to my Ubuntu machine (ODROID N2+ with Armbian), started Nautilus went to 'other locations' and saw my pc listed by name below 'Networks'. I clicked on it filled out my windows user name and password (Had to do that twice for some reason) and saw then all the shares for the PC listed. Note that 'WIndows network' is mentioned separate from my pc below the networks heading in Nautilus. And clicking on it still does not allows me to browse that item.